# Jquery DataTables default ordering columns by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have troubles ordering table columns by *date* using **Jquery Datatable**

it's an **Dynamic Table**, i have column `Created` displaying the date.

Here's my code :

**HTML**

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
            <td>2016-11-20 22:15:27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>janedoe@example.com</td>
            <td>2014-09-24 17:55:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>doe@example.com</td>
            <td>2017-12-22 05:13:01</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable();
```

this supposed to be ordered (2017 -> 2016 -> 2014).

i've searched and found answers, but all failed to achieve what i want to do.

e.g using `data-order` on the `<td>` didn't work.

```
<td data-order="2014-09-24 17:55:30">Lorem ipsum</td>
```

also using `moment.js` didn't work.

How can i achieve that?

---

**Edit**

i was reversing the date format, i was using **DD/MM/YYYY** but it worked with **YYYY/MM/DD**

after that i added the correct date format to `data-order` then set the default order column

`<td data-order="date('Y-m-d H:i:s')">Lorem ipsum</td>`

`$('#dataTable').DataTable({"order": [[2, "desc"]]});`

now it works.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy no errors in the console.

Comment: i copied your code to jsfiddle and it works. Try https://jsfiddle.net/jcbnm8t2/

Comment: The code works, i want to order the columns by date (the date column) e.g order by latest (2017 > 2016 > 2014)

Comment: you need to use a plugin apparently https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Comment: Can you give me code example? in the same jsfiddle pen, please?

Comment: ordering works when you click on the header of the `created` column

Comment: or you want this order by default?

Comment: Yes, i want the default order sir. order by latest by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default order for a column by index like this:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({"order": [[2, "desc"]]});
```

Note that it will order not actually by date but by numbers. It works fine for dates like `Y\m\d` but for dates like `d\m\Y` you should use plugin https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ as pointed out by [@Daniel Lizik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4769440/daniel-lizik)
Try:

```js
$('#dataTable').DataTable({"order": [[2, "desc"]]});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
            <td>2016-11-20 22:15:27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>janedoe@example.com</td>
            <td>2014-09-24 17:55:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>doe@example.com</td>
            <td>2017-12-22 05:13:01</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That didn't order by date, it only set the default order column but didn't order it correctly, it gave me (2017 > 2014 > 2016), you get that?

Comment: I see in your run-code-snipped, that ordered it correctly, let me check my code maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: Now it's working like a charm! but here's a note, i was reversing the date format, i was using dd/mm/yyyy but it only works with yyyy/mm/dd, also after adding that correct format to ```data-order``` add the default order to that column ```"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]``` and it works! please add these notes to the answer for future visitors, thank's for the help i appreciate that.